# how to develop a depedent datepickers in jquery with month & years using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

i already have a one JSFiddle but it not working as expected, If the user directly selects the end-date it is not restricting the start-date in this fiddle. It must change the once the user directly change the end-date. it is working fine for first selecting the start-date. It is not working when user directly selects the end-date. please assist me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#projectStartDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                maxDate:'-1M',
                yearRange:'1975:c+10',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

                    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));


              }


            });
            $("#projectStartDate").focus(function() {
                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
                    my: "center top",
                    at: "center bottom",
                    of: $(this)
                });
            });
        });



        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#projectCompletedDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                minDate: $("#projectStartDate").datepicker('getDate'),
                maxDate:0,
                yearRange:'1975:c+10',
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();


                    $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));


                }
            });
            $("#projectCompletedDate").focus(function() {
                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
                    my: "center top",
                    at: "center bottom",
                    of: $(this)
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is the Fiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/gL7uW/12/

Comment: Please improve your question, you have to add code with a jsfiddle. Also your description has language errors and I have no idea what you mean. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Just add these line to

$('#first-datepicker') Close event

```
$("#second-datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
```

and $('#second-datepicker') close event

```
$("#first-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
```

Final Code :

```
$('#first-datepicker').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            setMyDate(inst);
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            saveMyDate(inst);

            var secondDatePicker = $('#second-datepicker').data('datepicker');
            var dateSetted = secondDatePicker.input.data('date-setted');

            setMyDate(secondDatePicker);

            secondDatePicker.input.datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 0));     

            if (dateSetted == true) {
                saveMyDate(secondDatePicker);
            };

            $("#second-datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        }
    });

    $('#second-datepicker').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            setMyDate(inst);
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            saveMyDate(inst);
            $("#first-datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
        }
    });
```